Segmentation Error in data structure C language, about linked list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char element[100];

typedef struct ListNode {
    element data;
    struct ListNode *link;
} ListNode;

void error(char *message)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(1);
}
ListNode* insert_first(ListNode *head, element value){
    if(strcmp(value, "head") == 0 || strcmp(value, "NULL") == 0 ){
        printf("You should not try the keyword, 'head' and 'NULL'\n");
        return head;
    }    
    ListNode *p = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    strcpy(p->data, value);
    p->link = head;
    head = p;
    return head;
}
void print_list(ListNode *head){
    for (ListNode *p = head; p != NULL; p = p->link)
        printf("%s->", p->data);
    printf("NULL\n");
    return;
}

ListNode* search_list(ListNode *head, element x){
    ListNode *p = head;

    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Nothing here. Insert First.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(strcmp(x, "head") == 0 || strcmp(x, "NULL") == 0 ){
        printf("You can not try the keyowrd, 'head' and 'NULL'\n");
        return head;
    }
    else{
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(p->data, x) == 0) {
                printf("There is  %s.\n", x);
                return head;
            }
            p = p->link;
        }
        printf("We can't find %s.\n", x);
        exit(1);

}}

ListNode* delete(ListNode *head, element x){
    if(strcmp(x, "head") == 0 || strcmp(x, "NULL") == 0 ){
        printf("You can not try the keyowrd, 'head' and 'NULL'\n");
        return head;
    }
    else if(head == NULL){
        printf("There is nothing\n");
        return head;
    }
    else{
        ListNode *p = head;
        ListNode *pre = NULL; // 수정된 부분: 이전 노드를 가리키는 포인터 초기화
        element data_index;
        strcpy(data_index, p->data);
        if(strcmp(data_index, x) == 0){
            head = head->link;
            free(p);
            return head;
        }
        else{
            while (p != NULL){
                if (strcmp(data_index, x) == 0) {
                    if(pre != NULL) // 수정된 부분: 삭제할 노드가 첫 번째 노드가 아닌 경우
                        pre->link = p->link;
                    free(p);
                    return head;
                }
                pre = p; // 수정된 부분: 이전 노드 갱신
                p = p->link;
                if(p != NULL) // 수정된 부분: p가 NULL이 아닐 때만 data_index 갱신
                    strcpy(data_index, p->data);
            }
            printf("We can't find %s.\n", x);
        }
    }
    return head;}
int main(void){
    ListNode *head = NULL;
    element data;

    strcpy(data, "APPLe");
    head = insert_first(head, data);
    print_list(head);

    strcpy(data, "Kiwi");
    head = insert_first(head, data);
    print_list(head);

    search_list(head, data);

    delete(head, data);
    search_list(head, data);

    strcpy(data, "APPLe");
    search_list(head, data);
}

I make this code for a college's task. I have to create an insert, delete, and print_all in linked list.
But, in line 49,
        if (strcmp(p->data, x) == 0) {

there is  segmentation error.
I know that a segmentation error means wrong memory reference. But I can't solve this error. You don't need to know the answer code. Just let me know the direction that I can grow!!

your code works fine: APPLe->NULL Kiwi->APPLe->NULL There is  Kiwi. We can't find Kiwi.

tested this with online compiler, nothing seems wrong. works with no errors.

@amd You don't have any error???????

https://godbolt.org/z/n5Yqev1Ye cmon links people

Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where

@erik258 https://godbolt.org/z/YzPYTTbhr

delete returns a value. Think about it for a moment. Why does it need to return a value? And what happens when you ignore the returned value?

head = delete(head, data); - but it delete is overly complicated.  You could simplify it a lot. example

@n.m.couldbeanAI You guys save my life.. realllllllly Thank you :)

I dont know why it can be solved by remove the return a value in delete. But I have to study more

You could send in a ListNode** to delete instead if you want skip returning it - but that makes delete different from your other functions so either stick with returning a pointer to head or rewrite insert_first too to take a ListNode**. It could look like this

That come from your first delete(head, data)
Because you don't update the head pointer :
delete(head, data); // missing `head =`
search_list(head, data);

strcpy(data, "APPLe");
search_list(head, data); // trying to read the wrong head ptr

I also want to make a point.
You NEED to check if malloc() fail
ListNode *p = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
strcpy(p->data, value);

Even if that not where is the bug, that bad.
It's also "cool" to have a function to free out all list after usage.
Here a SIMPLE list implementation for string if you want to take a look :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_list
{
    char *          data;
    struct s_list * next;
}   t_list;

void
lst_free(t_list * head)
{
    t_list * ptr;

    if (head == NULL)
        return ;

    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        free(ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    free(head);
    return ;
}

t_list *
lst_add_front(t_list * head, char * value)
{
    t_list * new_node;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(t_list));
    if (new_node == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    new_node->data = strdup(value);
    if (new_node->data == NULL)
    {
        free(new_node);
        return (NULL);
    }
    new_node->next = head;
    return (new_node);
}

t_list *
lst_delete(t_list * head, char * value)
{
    t_list * ptr;
    t_list * dady;

    ptr = head;
    dady = NULL;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(head->data, value) == 0)
        {
            free(ptr->data);
            if (dady == NULL)
                head = ptr->next;
            else
                dady->next = ptr->next;
            free(ptr);
            break ;
        }
        dady = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return (head);
}

char *
lst_find(t_list * head, char * value)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return (NULL);

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(head->data, value) == 0)
            return (head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void
lst_print(t_list * head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return ;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s->", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    return ;
}

int main(void)
{
    t_list *    list = NULL;
    char *      res;

    list = lst_add_front(list, "APPLe");

    lst_print(list);

    list = lst_add_front(list, "Kiwi");

    lst_print(list);

    res = lst_find(list, "Kiwi");
    printf("find : %s\n", res);

    list = lst_delete(list, "Kiwi");

    res = lst_find(list, "Kiwi");
    printf("find : %s\n", res);

    res = lst_find(list, "APPLe");
    printf("find : %s\n", res);

    lst_free(list);
    return (0);
}

Output :
APPLe->NULL
Kiwi->APPLe->NULL
find : Kiwi
find : (null)
find : APPLe 

